# How to attract FIFA players?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

FIFA 12 hit the shelves a week ago and has a player base of a multiple million people all over the world.

Unfortunately there are hardly any FIFA players on gaming.SE, you can count the amount of previous FIFA title questions on two hands and for [fifa-12](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fifa-12) the number of questions and answers is really low as well. (most are from me so far)

It definitly is not a game-related problem, because there are a lot of things to ask about FIFA and a lot of new modes and features that confuse newcomers, not even taking into account the complex *Ultimate Team* mode.

So, what can we do to bring more Fifa players here, apart from the obvious solution (asking and answering questions myself)?

Is it for example considered bad to make ontopic advertisement for GSE in the EA forums? Something like:

> I have a question about XYZ/how does ABC work? I also asked this here: [link to gaming.SE]

Getting more FIFA players here would definitly help gaming.SE and it would also help the FIFA base, because the EA forums are not a good place to get answers imho.

Comment: Give out free copies of FIFA 12 to everybody!

Comment: If you give me the funding. ;)

Comment: It is on my list of games to buy, but there are SO many games coming out this fall, had to cut some from my list for now.

Comment: @atticae we reduced the rep requirement on the grant to 500 rep, so have at it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might well extend the question to all EA titles, and beyond that, to all sports titles ... and even so, the answer will likely be the same as it is for any other game. To attract people interested in a topic, we must have quality questions and quality answers about it.

Whether it's FIFA or Madden or NBA or what have you, what will draw most people here is searching for something about the games they enjoy and finding the answer here. We can use existing tools to make our questions more visible (although for the most part, Google takes care of that itself – it does not take long for a question on Gaming to rise near the top of search results for a specific question), but beyond that, it's up to us.

If you have questions about Ultimate Team mode, and no one has answers, see if there are ways you can work them out yourself, and then post what you find. Sometimes that's the only way you'll get the information you need ... and doing so might draw more players here to help with your other FIFA questions. (I'm doing something similar for my Madden question about UT.)

Answer (score 7):

Why would we go for anything but the obvious solution?

Spamming the EA forums sounds like the worst possible option.

Comment: Heh, maybe I phrased it unfortunately. I am not lucking for an alternative to asking and answering questions, but for additional ways to draw FIFA users to this site. Also I never thought about any kind of spamming.

Comment: I can think of worse options...

Answer (score 4):

While posting to the EA forums might not go over so well, if you have a personal social network of Fifa players (like your Facebook friends), you can definitely plug the site to them.  One of the best ways to do this is to post a link to an existing question/answer they would be interested in.

Answer (score 3):

Be the change you want to see, man -- apply for a FIFA 12 game in the promotion grant, and ask (and answer) questions about it!

[Gaming Promotional Grant - Round 7](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2995/gaming-promotional-grant-round-7)

Comment: I already have one, but thanks. ;)