# Gaming Promotional Grant - Round 7

Tags: discussion, promotional-grant

> ## This round has now closed.
>
> Team is doing its best and preparing now. Please wait warmly until it is ready.

Welcome to the Seventh round of the **Gaming Promotional Grant**. This is an effort where users of the community will receive one free game on behalf of Stack Exchange. What's the catch?

Simple - ask questions and post answers to questions about the new game you got, have fun while helping us create a wonderful database of information on our own site here for the new game. We've had absolutely roaring success with games like *The Witcher 2* and *Deus Ex: Human Revolution*, so let's keep the iron hot, shall we?

This time, we'll be following the basic rules as outlined in [the proposal post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2972/gaming-grant-rework-proposal-20-games-every-two-weeks).

> Users with at least **500** reputation apply by filling out a form that specifies **one game of their choice** of new or upcoming games for the current big platforms. **Up to 20 users will be selected** from this pool pseudo-randomly, and will be reimbursed for their own purchase of the games after **scanning and emailing the receipts (or through Steam or Amazon)**.

We're using <s>1000</s> 500 as the limit to test the waters here.

"Big platforms" means **XBox 360, PS3, Wii, and PC**. What games are coming out this week, and the next two weeks after that? Courtesy of [GameSpot](http://www.gamespot.com), here are the current and upcoming games releases for the weeks beginning with...

- October 2, 2011: [PC](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=5&date=2011-10-02&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [PS3](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1028&date=2011-10-02&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Xbox](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1029&date=2011-10-02&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Wii](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1031&date=2011-10-02&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore)
- October 9, 2011: [PC](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=5&date=2011-10-09&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [PS3](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1028&date=2011-10-09&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Xbox](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1029&date=2011-10-09&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Wii](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1031&date=2011-10-09&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore)
- October 16, 2011: [PC](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=5&date=2011-10-16&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [PS3](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1028&date=2011-10-16&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Xbox](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1029&date=2011-10-16&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Wii](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1031&date=2011-10-16&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore)

[MetaCritic](http://www.metacritic.com/) also has a nifty overlook of upcoming games, filterable by  your preferred platform: [PC](http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/release-date/coming-soon/pc/date?view=detailed), [PS3](http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/release-date/coming-soon/ps3/date?view=detailed), [Xbox](http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/release-date/coming-soon/xbox360/date?view=detailed), [Wii](http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/release-date/coming-soon/wii/date?view=detailed).

#### Applications have closed.

(For those curious, this is considered parallel to the [Gaming Grant Fall 2011 Special Episode](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2962/gaming-fall-2011-grant-results), so this is a prime opportunity for those who didn't get picked in there to step up to the plate.)

Comment: Is Rage fair game for a *second* time? It already got its own promotion, and it's the first item on the PC list, there.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure about how useful that list is - two of its listing are Civ V (out for over a year) and Portal 2 (which got updated with FREE DLC, that doesn't need to be bought).

Comment: @RavenDreamer the GameSpot release list is just a set of guidelines; if you know of a better game release list we can link to for each platform, we can switch to that.

Comment: (also IMHO Rage is a very, very bad game and I regret spending $60 of my own money on it. FWIW)

Comment: @JeffAtwood I haven't played RAGE, but I haven't been hearing good things about it.  And I almost signed up for it in the previous signups!

Comment: So, if I'm getting a game from the Fall 2011 Gaming Grant, can I not apply for another one?  I hadn't realized that Ratchet and Clank: All 4 One was due out already.

Comment: @Powerlord anyone can apply, selection is random every time. Just make sure you ask and answer questions about your game if selected!

Comment: When does this promotion end?

Comment: How motivating that I have to wait until Friday to play a game Jeff is calling a waste of money

Comment: @ivo well at least you didn't pay for it, man! I didn't want it to suck but holy moly it's bad. IMHO of course, but.. http://arstechnica.com/gaming/2011/10/rage-is-the-gamiest-game-that-ever-gamed.ars

Comment: @IvoFlipse Jeff thinks Just Cause 2 is the greatest game of all time, or close to it. so remember, it's just his opinion. :)

Comment: @doozer hey, "Yahtzee" Croshaw of Zero Punctuation named Just Cause 2 his "Game of the Year"!

Comment: @JeffAtwood Really? I thought that guy hated everything. I tried it, just wasn't up my alley, not a bad game by any means. Just starting out Rage, waiting to form an opinion of it.

Comment: @JeffAtwood Totally deserves it, man. I got Just Cause 2 after reading your blog post review thing on it and it's probably the most fun I've had with a video game in a while.

Comment: I played Just Cause 2 after Jeff blogged about it, it was fun, but I didn't finish it (got boring after a while)

Comment: I'd recommend http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/release-date/coming-soon/all/date as a list of upcoming releases.

Comment: Since @JeffAtwood seems to be watching this thread (and even [posted it on twitter!](https://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror/statuses/122118112156987392)), I figure this is as good a place as any to mention this: I think the gaming grants are awesome, and I think Brett and the mods have been doing a great job.  Thanks to you all!

Comment: First time I've seen one of these promotions and spent about half an hour looking at promotional material for Dungeon Defenders. Actually looks like a fun game - I'm in!

Comment: This is a really awesome thing. No games I plan on getting within the next couple of weeks, but I will keep my eye out for future rounds. SE you are amazing!

Comment: So according to the rules, pre-purchase of **Battlefield 3** or **MW3** is not a valid option?

Comment: @vartec What's the release date on those? If it is far after the current round, you could always wait until a later round.

Comment: @vartec: No, but Battlefield 3 will be available in the next round and MW3 in the one after.

Comment: I think I'll go ahead and wait for a chance to get a free MW3. Why oh why could you guys not have created this promotion so I could've tried to get Gears 3 for free!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Congratulations! 20 users have been selected. An email has been sent to the address you supplied, with a subject line of **Gaming Promotional Grant Selection**. Let me know if you didn't get it, but I've got 20 items in my outbox so I know you should have it. ♪

> For those who didn't get selected: tune in **Monday, October 17th** for **Round 8**'s start!

The winners of Round 7 are as follows, grouped by game:

### Ratchet & Clank All 4 One

fbrereto
SilverM-A
Powerlord

### Orcs Must Die!

Ian Pugsley
Ullallulloo

### Rune Factory: Tides of Destiny

Latency

### FIFA 12

jwaddell

### Might & Magic: Heroes VI

Between this huge roll and the Fall Grant, I sure hope to see a huge amount of content on this site for this.

Apreche
cristina
Josefvz
Bruce Connor
Dan Rasmussen

### Dungeon Defenders

mordi2k
AndyPerfect
Mr. November

### Dark Souls

YellowMegaMan
Craig Pilgrim
Sylvain Defresne
Phileosophos

### Batman: Arkham City

Solivagant

Comment: For the receipt that was online, do I need to take a screenshot of the receipt page or what?

Comment: @Powerlord Usually, the provider will give you the option to print the receipt for your own keeping, if not just save it to file. In the print case, most people print it as a PDF. A screenshot will do if the service doesn't provide the capability, but I'd be amazed if they didn't give you such a way.

Comment: It may be because they haven't yet shipped the game.  I still have the option to Cancel the order on my screen.

Comment: I am going to buy Orcs Must Die! and Dungeon Defenders too. They seems fun and probably they have many content do discuss here. ;p

Comment: I answered the email sent to me, but no response. When will I receive my Amazon gift card? Do I have to wait for the release of the game? I hope not! It would be a shame to lose the bonus pre-order.

Comment: I too have responded for a Steam gift but have not heard back. I'm getting a little anxious because Might & Magic comes out in 12 hours, but I'll wait patiently til I hear I should do otherwise. =]

Comment: @Dan We sent out the Might & Magic orders yesterday and the day prior. I can confirm we received your mail and already ordered the game. You should already have the game.

Comment: @GraceNote - I just double checked my email and Steam account, and haven't received a second email or game gift. Feel free to email me if you need to discuss this further.

Comment: @GraceNote Thanks for the promotion guys! Might and magic is already in my steam library. I'll be playing a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Orcs Must Die! looks good. It's a tower defense/third-person shooter from Robot Entertainment, the studio that was founded by the founders of Ensemble Studios after Microsoft shut them down. [It got a good review on Ars too.](http://arstechnica.com/gaming/reviews/2011/10/xbla-pc-orcs-must-die-adds-third-person-action-to-tower-defense.ars)

Answer (score 3):

Dark Souls seems like it might be the kind of game that will be producing a lot of questions over the next few months. All the talk I see about it describes the game as challenging but fair, rewarding skillful play. It should also sell better than Demons Souls due to being on multiple platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Family Feud 2012 Edition. You will be mine!

Answer (score 1):

Ratchet and Clank: All 4 One for the PS3 is on the list for a October 18th release.

You know you want to get it to play it coop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if Australia is valid for this considering our games are hella expensive; I nominated Arkham City because it's definitely coming out in two weeks, but I'll likely pick up the new Ratchet & Clank as well when it comes out, even though it's only listed as coming out in the next two weeks in the US.

Comment: Yeah, I'm also not sure if Brazil would be valid.

Comment: @Wilerson Pretty sure everywhere is valid unless you're in North Korea or something and it's impossible to reimburse you for a game :P