# Gaming Promotional Grant - Round 8

Tags: discussion, promotional-grant

> ### This round has closed
>
> Team is doing its best and preparing. Please wait warmly until it is ready.

Welcome to the Eighth round of the **Gaming Promotional Grant**. Users in good standing can receive one free game on behalf of Gaming Stack Exchange. What's the catch?

Simple - ask questions and post answers to questions about your new game; have fun while helping us create a wonderful database of information on our own site here for the new game. Here's how it works:

> Users with at least **500** reputation are eligible to apply. Fill out a form specifying **one game of your choice** of new or upcoming games for the current big platforms. **Up to 20 users will be selected** from this pool pseudo-randomly, and will be reimbursed for their purchase of the game by one of these methods:
>
> - Scan and email your game receipt to us; we'll reimburse through PayPal
> - [Steam gift](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?p_faqid=549)
> - [Amazon gift card](http://www.amazon.com/gp/gc)

(500 reputation worked well last time, so we'll be sticking with it. Note that there have been a couple changes to the workflow from the last time. The most significant change is that *the default reimbursement route will be PayPal*.)

If you're selected, you'll receive simple instructions via email detailing all the information you'll have to provide to get reimbursed. **If you won in [the previous round](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2995/gaming-promotional-grant-round-7/3018#3018), you are not eligible to win a game in this round**.

"Big platforms" means **XBox 360, PS3, Wii, and PC**. What games are eligible? Any game coming out this week or the next two weeks:

- October 16, 2011: [PC](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=5&date=2011-10-16&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [PS3](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1028&date=2011-10-16&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Xbox](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1029&date=2011-10-16&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Wii](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1031&date=2011-10-16&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore)
- October 23, 2011: [PC](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=5&date=2011-10-23&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [PS3](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1028&date=2011-10-23&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Xbox](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1029&date=2011-10-23&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Wii](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1031&date=2011-10-23&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore)
- October 30, 2011: [PC](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=5&date=2011-10-30&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [PS3](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1028&date=2011-10-30&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Xbox](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1029&date=2011-10-30&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Wii](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1031&date=2011-10-30&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore)

Any game released later than this should be selected in the *next* round. [MetaCritic](http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/release-date/coming-soon/) also has a general list of upcoming games, filterable by your preferred platform: [PC](http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/release-date/coming-soon/pc/date?view=detailed), [PS3](http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/release-date/coming-soon/ps3/date?view=detailed), [Xbox](http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/release-date/coming-soon/xbox360/date?view=detailed), [Wii](http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/release-date/coming-soon/wii/date?view=detailed).

#### Applications have closed

The answers below are a good place to note any games you think will be hot picks. You may convert people to your cause, or perhaps get converted yourself! Just keep an open mind, neh? Once the selection process is closed (this will happen over the course of a *couple days*), we will close applications and the 20 winners will be posted in an answer that I'll accept.

Comment: @Matthew While the decision was made independently of it, no one actually used Moneybookers last time, so we're just standardizing that option to PayPal. Steam and Amazon are still available without needing PayPal.

Comment: @Jeff I thought that we were doing the two weeks after this week? A game coming out earlier this week would make someone wait a week to get the game, kind of defeating the point of this.

Comment: @Jeff Is Origin a valid way of getting reimbursed?  I put down "Steam" on my application for BF3, but I wanted to select "Origin"

Comment: @ull good point, I guess we'll keep doing three weeks just for coverage even though there is a tiny bit of overlap. Ideally you should be buying these highly anticipated games yourself *anyway* as soon as they are released; the reimbursement selection is merely icing on the cake :)

Comment: @dave we have to limit the reimbursement forms for the sake of sanity and scalability; anything outside of Steam or Amazon is of the "send us the receipt and we'll reimburse you via PayPal" form.

Comment: @GraceNote I applied for Dungeon Defenders but I just had a friend who I have a history of co-op gaming with gift it to me. You can ignore my application!

Comment: May I change my application from Batman: Arkham City to Battlefield 3? Batman got delayed here in Brazil...

Comment: @JeffAtwood: For the PayPal, but for Amazon and especially Steam you don't really want to buy it first if you'll be getting it for free.

Comment: @ull is there some particular reason you can't just get reimbursed in that case?

Comment: @JeffAtwood: Yeah, but you can't get reimbursed via Amazon or Steam then.

Comment: @ulla sure you can -- money is money, it's just a question of sending the receipt in and getting the PayPal reimbursement in return.

Comment: @JeffAtwood: Yes, you can still get reimbursed, but not through Amazon and Steam which are two valid reimbursement methods.

Comment: @Jeff I dunno, for example I'm considering to apply for SS:BF3 in the next few rounds, but if I didn't get selected I wouldn't buy it right away and just wait for a steam sale to bring it down to dirt cheap.

Comment: When is the next round likely to open? It's been over two weeks since this round opened.

Comment: @jwaddell I don't know, I'm going to email some folks -- the next round should have started already and I'm not sure why it has not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An astute observer may notice that the number of winners for this round is... not 20. If this were a "good news bad news" kind of deal, I'd say "The good news is, everyone who applied won!" Because that's what happened. We only got this many applicants, and not every application was actually for a game in the grant period. This is a substantial decrease from the number of applicants in the last round, so something is up. But, dwelling is a subject for another time. Onwards, to our winners!

Those who have won should receive an email with a subject line of **Gaming Stack Exchange Promotional Grant Selection** detailing how to receive their reimbursement. This email will be sent to the same email address that you specified when applying, so keep an eye out on it.

#### Battlefield 3

Wilerson
Dave McClelland

#### Kirby: Return to Dreamland

Ashley Nunn

#### Serious Sam: The Random Encounter

badp

#### Sword of the Stars II: Lords of Winter

fireDude67

#### Take On Helicopters

ProSay

#### Uncharted 3: Drake's Deception

Crag
Merus
Doozer Blake
Kotsu

#### Worms Crazy Golf Fun Pack

Matthew Read

Comment: I haven't been applying because I'm on game overload right now.  I've barely started HOMM 6,  haven't finished Tropico or SpaceChem, barely started Frozen Synapse, and have Skyrim coming in two short weeks!

Comment: @bwarner That's mostly why I've never applied, either.

Comment: @GraceNote You mean it's a decrease from the *last* round, right?

Comment: Might be that everyone is just waiting for the chance to re-queue for Skyrim. I know I am. From what I've gathered, entering for 2 consecutive grants is an automatic disqualification.

Comment: @lunboks *Winning* in two consecutive grants is disallowed, not simply entering. But, that said, entering without intending to win is traditionally quite backwards.

Comment: That's also why I haven't applied.  I have 2 games coming in from the fall promotion and I have quite the backlog of games I'm still trying to get through before 11/11/11 hits.  And then there's dungeon defenders which is absolutely addicting for some reason.

Comment: :( LOTR: War in the North just became available on Steam. Can I change to that?

Comment: how long does it take for us to receive our game?

Comment: @GraceNote I got an email back from you when I sent my receipt, but still haven't gotten the reimbursement.  No rush, but should I resend the email?

Comment: @Dave No need to resend, I'll later double check on the status for you.

Comment: @GraceNote - any word on why I haven't received my copy of Kirby: Return to Dreamland? I am just curious where it may have ended up.

Comment: @Ashley I sent an inquiry. I haven't gotten word back yet.

Comment: @GraceNote thanks for checking. I really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 2):

[Take on helicopters](http://store.steampowered.com/app/65730/) looks nice to look at, but I'm curious as to whether it'd be fun to play.

Lots of simulators fall short in their ambitions. It feels a little like that Bus simulator in my mind.

Answer (score 2):

Batman Arkham city is probably the big one, too bad the PC version was delayed.

Comment: Available for pre-purchase now: http://store.steampowered.com/app/57400/

Comment: If the account SE uses to buy them on steam owns Arkham Asylum or LEGO Batman, Arkham city is 20% off (U$S 39.99) if pre-ordered

Comment: @Jual I got excited for a moment then, followed by *"This item is currently unavailable in your region"* -- lovely, is this another game that UK retailers have arranged to only be purchasable by retail on release? Madness. And such a pain in the arse. >.<

Comment: @juan ooh, that is a good deal.. cancelling my Amazon order in favor of Steam for that.

Answer (score 2):

[Dungeon Defenders](http://store.steampowered.com/app/65800/) is another game that may generate a bit of questions as its heavy item and skill based.

Comment: I really am interested in this game! Looks like fun!

Comment: @Raven Dreamer I bought the 4 pack for me and three friends, we split the cost so it came out to be $10 each, you should probably do the same, I'm sure there are some on this site who are also interested.

Comment: @yx. I did the same. I think it came to $10 U.S. with some change split 4 ways through the Steam 4 pack, which is a great deal. Looking forward to playing this tonight.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Uncharted 3: Drake's Deception](http://www.naughtydog.com/games/uncharted) will be a big one for this round. I myself can't wait to get my hands on it, free or not!

Comment: Isn't that until next round?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the release date for the game is November 1st for U.S., which would be in two weeks which makes it eligible according to the application.

Comment: That's confusing. In the application it says "get reimbursed for one new (released this week) or upcoming (will be released in the next two weeks) game on Xbox 360, PS3, Wii, or PC". If it's not eligible, what should I do if I already submitted an entry?

Comment: @Kotsu Jeff edited his post and clarified. Uncharted is part of it with the week of Oct. 30th being included, which is good, because I put in for it as well.

Comment: That would be a bummer, I picked Assassins Creed Revelations, because Uncharted **wasn't** on the original list...

Answer (score 0):

[Kirby's Return to Dreamland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirby%27s_Return_to_Dreamland)! <3

Answer (score 0):

Come on, someone's got to try out [GoldenEye 007: Reloaded](http://goldeneyegame.com/#/news) ... not me, I've already got grants to work through plus time set aside for Skyrim, but I'm sure there are people looking to recreate that N64 experience with trophies or achievements ...