# Gaming Promotional Grant - The Ninth Round (Starting November 4th)

Tags: discussion, promotional-grant

> #### Applications are closed

Welcome to the Ninth round of the **Gaming Promotional Grant**. Users in good standing can receive one free game on behalf of Gaming Stack Exchange. What's the catch?

Simple - ask questions and post answers to questions about your new game; have fun while helping us create a wonderful database of information on our own site here for the new game. Here's how it works:

> Users with at least **500** reputation are eligible to apply. Fill out a form specifying **one game of your choice** of new or upcoming games for the current big platforms. **Up to 20 users will be selected** from this pool pseudo-randomly, and will be reimbursed for their purchase of the game by one of these methods:
>
> - Scan and email your game receipt to us; we'll reimburse through PayPal
> - [Steam gift](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?p_faqid=549)
> - Ordered and mailed through Amazon.com (or appropriate national branch)

If you're selected, you'll receive simple instructions via email detailing all the information you'll have to provide to get reimbursed. **If you won in [the previous round](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/gaming-promotional-grant-round-8/3094#3094), you are not eligible to win a game in this round**.

"Big platforms" means **XBox 360, PS3, Wii, and PC**. What games are eligible? Any game coming out this week or the next two weeks:

- October 30, 2011: [PC](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=5&date=2011-10-30&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [PS3](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1028&date=2011-10-30&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Xbox](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1029&date=2011-10-30&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Wii](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1031&date=2011-10-30&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore)
- November 6, 2011: [PC](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=5&date=2011-11-06&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [PS3](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1028&date=2011-11-06&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Xbox](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1029&date=2011-11-06&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Wii](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1031&date=2011-11-06&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore)
- November 13, 2011: [PC](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=5&date=2011-11-13&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [PS3](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1028&date=2011-11-13&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Xbox](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1029&date=2011-11-13&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Wii](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1031&date=2011-11-13&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore)

Any game released later than this should be selected in the *next* round. [MetaCritic](http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/release-date/coming-soon/) also has a general list of upcoming games, filterable by your preferred platform: [PC](http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/release-date/coming-soon/pc/date?view=detailed), [PS3](http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/release-date/coming-soon/ps3/date?view=detailed), [Xbox](http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/release-date/coming-soon/xbox360/date?view=detailed), [Wii](http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/release-date/coming-soon/wii/date?view=detailed).

#### Closed

---

This round is starting a bit late. Nevertheless, [certain big games are coming right around the corner](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/11/elder-scrolls-v-vs-modern-warfare-3/), among all other things coming out next week. Applications will close on **Sunday, November 6th** at the end of the UTC day, so that we can order games in time for people.

Another announcement - Steam has recently been repeatedly refusing to let us buy things. I don't know why. We had a one day break from that behavior before it started blocking us again. So, if you opt for a Steam reimbursement, keep in mind that we may not be able to gift it to you in time if they continue to block us. It may be more effective to use the standard reimbursement route.

Comment: Is Amazon gift card reimbursement new? Last round it was ordered and shipped for you (supposed to be, emailed separately about mine which hasn't arrived)

Comment: @Doozer I... uh... huh? It still is ordering and shipping, I don't know why my text copy changed... let me fix that...

Comment: I wonder if last round's low turnout was partially due to people "saving up" for this round...

Comment: There that, and the fact that there are quite a few winners still from the fall grant that are already getting games during this time.

Comment: Steam might be getting fussy about all the gifting, particularly since you're gifting to people in different regions.  They apparently get fussy if you try to buy from a country that doesn't match your billing address (although I never had that problem) so that seems like a "logical" extension.  You may want to contact them directly.

Comment: @Matthew Don't think we haven't tried contacting them directly. Many times. Their lack of response is as stubborn as their refusal to let us buy, as it were.

Comment: Yeah, I've also heard that their support sucks :P

Comment: Is that special first grant still valid or should I apply now for Assassin's Creed? It was never clear to me if I would be getting it from that grant.

Comment: Do you mean the Fall Grant that Brett ran with those 10 games, @Juan? Yes, that is still valid and runs parallel to this one (so it is independent).

Comment: Yes, that one. I applied back then for AC:R, and since it was very confusing I was wondering if I should apply again in this one. I'll wait then.

Comment: Arkham city is about to come out for the PC, but it is already out for consoles. Does the PC version count as possible game?

Comment: @JuanManuel: It's valid AFAIK.  Just contact Brett about it and he'll set things in motion.  I did and I guess it's just a matter of time till the reimbursement comes in.

Comment: Is the list of winners going to be posted like before?  I'm honestly just curious to see, after all the fuss, how many people DID ask for Skyrim... :3

Comment: @Shinrai It'll be coming up soon.

Comment: @GraceNote: How soon?

Comment: @Ullallulloo Not very soon :P

Answer (score 7):

[Skyrim](http://www.elderscrolls.com/Skyrim) is no doubt one of the most anticipated titles of the year.

Comment: Does Skyrim count for this promotion, considering 10 people got it as part of the Fall Promotion?

Comment: @MarkTrapp Yes it does.

Comment: \*is sad he has to wait until Christmas\*

Answer (score 2):

You guys can keep your MW3 and your Skyrim, I'm most excited for [Assassin's Creed: Revelations](http://assassinscreed.ubi.com/revelations/en-us/home/index.aspx).

(Also maybe worth mentioning: Minecraft finally "releasing". EDIT: Although we obviously have [no shortage of Minecraft questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft).)

Comment: If I signed up for Minecraft, I feel that I would get in trouble...

Comment: @Ullallulloo Maybe we two can get reimbursed?  :P

Answer (score 2):

There's always Serious Sam 3: BFE.

Answer (score 1):

L.A. Noire finally arrives for PC. Have been waiting so long!

Comment: The "Complete Collection" might be a good thing to grab through this promotion.

Comment: I'm hearing that it's horribly glitchy and buggy and a terrible port, generally. :/

Answer (score 0):

[Sonic Generations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_Generations) seems to have gotten pretty good reviews, and I've played a few of the games before.

Comment: Really? I had heard somewhat bad things about it.

Comment: I've heard mixed reviews as well, tending to the poor side.

Comment: @Powerlord: There aren't any negative reviews on Metacritic. Some mixed, but most are positive...

Comment: So it's the first non-terrible Sonic game in like 10+ years? :P

Comment: @MatthewRead - Sonic Colors was generally well-received.

Answer (score 0):

[Jurassic Park: The Game](http://www.telltalegames.com/jurassicpark) comes out on November 15th.  Available for PC from [Telltale Games](http://www.telltalegames.com/jppreorder) or [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/201830/), Xbox 360 via Xbox Live Arcade, and PS3 via PSN.

The [Deluxe Edition](http://www.telltalegames.com/jppreorder) (PC only) is $39.99 until its official launch (likely $49.99 afterwards).  The standard edition's price has not yet been announced by TellTale, although Steam lists it as $29.99 ($26.99 until November 15th).

Side note: It's likely a sort of point and click adventure game, as that's the kind of game TellTale makes.

Comment: I played BTTF (also by them) and the game was objectively boring. I loved it because I'm a huge fan of the films and it continues the story. I think the same would apply here; just for Jurassic Park fans.

Comment: @JuanManuel They continued some other series as well.  I enjoyed some of the Sam and Max games, and Tales of Monkey Island was pretty good too.