# Gaming Grant Round 10 - Week of November 15th?

Tags: discussion, promotional-grant

> ### This round has been closed

Welcome to the first double digit, the tenth round of the **Gaming Promotional Grant**! Users in good standing can receive one free game on behalf of Gaming Stack Exchange. What's the catch?

Simple - ask questions and post answers to questions about your new game; have fun while helping us create a wonderful database of information on our own site here for the new game. Here's how it works:

> Users with at least **500** reputation are eligible to apply. Fill out a form specifying **one game of your choice** of new or upcoming games for the current big platforms. **Up to 20 users will be selected** from this pool pseudo-randomly, and will be reimbursed for their purchase of the game by one of these methods:
>
> - Scan and email your game receipt to us; we'll reimburse through PayPal
> - [Steam gift](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?p_faqid=549)
> - Ordered and mailed through Amazon.com (or appropriate national branch)

If you're selected, you'll receive simple instructions via email detailing all the information you'll have to provide to get reimbursed. **If you won in [the previous round](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3135/gaming-promotional-grant-the-ninth-round-starting-november-4th), you are not eligible to win a game in this round**.

"Big platforms" means **XBox 360, PS3, Wii, and PC**. What games are eligible? Any game coming out this week or the next two weeks:

- November 13, 2011: [PC](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=5&date=2011-11-13&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [PS3](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1028&date=2011-11-13&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Xbox](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1029&date=2011-11-13&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Wii](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1031&date=2011-11-13&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore)
- November 20, 2011: [PC](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=5&date=2011-11-20&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [PS3](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1028&date=2011-11-20&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Xbox](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1029&date=2011-11-20&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Wii](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1031&date=2011-11-20&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore)
- November 27, 2011: [PC](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=5&date=2011-11-27&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [PS3](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1028&date=2011-11-27&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Xbox](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1029&date=2011-11-27&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore), [Wii](http://www.gamespot.com/newthisweek.html?platform=1031&date=2011-11-27&mode=all&sort=rdate&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore)

Any game released later than this should be selected in the *next* round. [MetaCritic](http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/release-date/coming-soon/) also has a general list of upcoming games, filterable by your preferred platform: [PC](http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/release-date/coming-soon/pc/date?view=detailed), [PS3](http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/release-date/coming-soon/ps3/date?view=detailed), [Xbox](http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/release-date/coming-soon/xbox360/date?view=detailed), [Wii](http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/release-date/coming-soon/wii/date?view=detailed).

#### Applications are now closed

---

Honestly, I miss when I used to post Meta questions other than these, haha. ♪

Brett fixed Steam! So Steam is now an option.

No other announcements. Well, other than how our most recent week was a blast for hits! Hopefully we'll see a lot more action. For now, though, there's still more to cover! So get to applying if ye haven't already. ♪

Comment: Is there a known end date for this round?

Comment: @Doozer Probably next Sunday

Comment: How randomly is 'pseudo-randomly'?

Comment: @GnomeSlice Random

Comment: @GnomeSlice Pseudo-random usually means that a machine is making the decision.  While not *truely* random like rolling dice, it's random enough for most purposes.

Comment: What are (in general) the odds of winning?  I don't have any idea as to the number of active 500+ rep users of the site, so I have no idea how to calibrate my exciteomometer.

Comment: @agent The odds of winning have been pretty high as of late, since we haven't been able to get 20 applicants since the first run.

Comment: @GraceNote Any thought to making the Gaming Promotional Grants more obvious by using the same horizontal bar used for SkyrimVsMW3 on the public site when it was live? I wonder if people bother to check the meta note on the right-hand side and even know they are going on. I find it hard to believe there aren't more than 20 people with 500+ rep that wouldn't want a free game.

Comment: @Doozer This happens every 2 weeks - the top banner is undismissable because it is something that is meant that it should always be read. If it becomes something that is used too frequently for relatively minor matters, then people get conditioned to ignore it. So alas, system message is a no-no.

Comment: When does the next round start?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So here we go. Not nearly as many applicants as last round (not that you'd know yet. I'll fix that. Sometime), which yet again means we get full prizing to all applicants.

### Assassin's Creed: Revelations

Doozer Blake
agent86

### L.A. Noire: The Complete Edition

Kotsu

### Rayman Origins

GnomeSlice

### Saints Row: The Third

Dave McClelland
Mr Smooth
Nick
Aeo

### Serious Sam 3 BFE

badp

### The King of Fighters XIII

HenryHey

### The Legend of Zelda: Skyward Sword

Merus

Comment: not enough people because everyone else is still playing skyrim :P

Answer (score 7):

Of course, Zelda: Skyward Sword and its November 20th release is one of the big ones from this time period.

Some of us have that one already from the Fall gaming grant.

Comment: I'm definitely looking forward to getting that from the Fall grant.

Comment: This is pretty much the only thing of major note.

Comment: @Shinrai agreed, though there are a couple of special/complete editions of games coming out that people may be interested in (LB2, L.A Noire, Ultimate MVC3, etc.)

Comment: @Shinrai: Minecraft! *hides*

Answer (score 5):

**Saint's Row: The Third** might be of interest for this round too. It's been getting great reviews.

Comment: Oh, geez, I forgot about this (I thought it was out last week?).  Consider my Zelda comment scratched.

Comment: @Shinrai, came out yesterday for US/EU/AU!

Comment: It seems odd to me that this round is overlapping the third week of last round...

Comment: @Powerlord We do "Next two weeks" each time, and it happens every 2 weeks. There'll basically be that overlap every time.

Comment: @GraceNote: You are aware that favors games and gamers who want games released on even weeks of the year (this week being week 46)?

Comment: @Powerlord Ever so slightly, except in practice the actual applications haven't actually had all that much intersection. The majority of applications fall on the current week and the immediately following week, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 5):

[Rayman Origins](http://www.gamespot.com/rayman-origins/platform/xbox360) has been getting great reviews, and it looks like a throwback to the original Rayman games: the 'origins' if you will.

Comment: ...How did I not know about that? Rayman is awesome. :)