# Do you have an iPhone / iPad? Do you want a free copy of Infinity Blade II?

Tags: discussion, promotional-grant

[Infinity Blade 2](http://infinitybladegame.com/) comes out on December 1.  Now, I know this isn't a hard-core gamer's first choice, but the first one got good reviews and a [surprising number of views on the handful of questions we had](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinity-blade), so we want to give it a shot.

Pricing hasn't been announced yet, but since the first one was originally only $6, it's highly unlikely that the sequel will be priced at $60.  Since nobody would want to waste a normal [gaming grant](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3236/gaming-grant-round-10-week-of-november-15th) on a $6 game, we thought we'd just do a special call for volunteers who want a free copy of the game.  Gifting through the App Store *appears* to be easy, so if you'd like to play just post here and we'll get in contact with you.

All we ask is that you *ask and answer a few questions about the game* within a week or two of it coming out.  That's it!  It's easy!

We'll probably use the normal 500 rep requirement, unless we get really desperate.  If we get too many volunteers, we'll be choosier.

**Update** [Price is announced](http://www.gamepro.com/article/news/225125/infinity-blade-ii-will-cost-you-6-99/): $6.99.  That means we can give away 8.53x as many copies as we usually do for a game!  Sign up now if you want to play on Dec 1!

Comment: Can't do it through the normal Gaming Grant, anyway - mobile and handheld are barred. So! This be yer only chance to get this kind o' game through us!

Comment: Arrrrrrrrrrrrr.

Comment: Still iOS only, I see.  Boo - this looks like fun.

Comment: I'd love to, but I only have a 3G.

Comment: I'll take the .53 copy....

Comment: Sign me up, DROID X BITCHES

Comment: Bring it on! :D

Answer (score 5):

Sure, I had some fun playing it and answering questions on Gaming.SE.

I have an iPad (first generation) and an iPhone 4: if it's not universal, I'd prefer the version for iPad. But there's been a somewhat annoying trend to make games iPad 2 only that really don't need to be, so if that's the case with *Infinity Blade II*, I'll play it on iPhone 4 for the good of Gaming.SE.

---

Just an update: I got this last night (thanks!), but it will not load on any device I own. It just crashes to the springboard after it hits the title screen. The App Store reviews indicate a few dozen people having the same problem, so I'm going to wait until they put out an update.

Comment: Their site claims iPad 1 compatability, so you should be good.

Comment: I have the same result on my original iPad, iPhone 4 works nicely though (with some squinting...).

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like fun to me - I love playing games on my iPhone, so sign me up. :) The game looks pretty interesting. I have an iPhone3Gs, if that matters at all.

Answer (score 4):

I thought the first one was pretty cool, so sure, sign me up!

I'm assuming IB2 will be a universal app like the first one, but if not, I have an iPhone 3GS and an iPad 2 and would prefer the iPad version.

Answer (score 4):

I'm interested. I do a fair bit of iPhone gaming. iPhone 4, if version matters.

Answer (score 3):

I like playing games on my iPhone.

I liked Infinity Blade.

I suspect I will like Infinity Blade 2.

I like to ask and answer questions about games that I like.

(iPhone 4S. No iPad here.)

Answer (score 3):

iPhone 4, I'm very much game to spend the time I'm on here usefully by asking/answering questions :P

Answer (score 2):

The first was a bit of fun, hopefully the second will be worthy of more (and different) questions.

iPad version if it's not universal.

Answer (score 2):

Sign me up. I never played the first one, but the second is looking sweet.

iPad 2.

Answer (score 1):

If there's still some left, I'd like to try it.
I have an iPhone 4 and an iPad 2 (if it's not universal I'd prefer it for the iPad)

Answer (score 1):

I'm big on iPhone games, I'd love a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Don't quite have the rep, but would like to check it out my wife's iPhone and see if it really is that much better than Android :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested,  I own both an IPad 2 and an Iphone 4s, plus have a holiday break coming up.